# what method can be used to send data to the arduino

Tags: c++, opencv, serial-port, arduino-uno, serial-communication

I want to send the output data from OpenCV to the Arduino to control some actuator. I'm doing a sorting and packing line for apple fruit
thanks in advance

" I modified this code, it works fine but when connect it to the OpenCV its not, the code was able to send the numbers manually to the Arduino "

```
     #include"stdafx.h"
     using namespace System;
     using namespace System::IO::Ports;

    int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
    {
SerialPort port("COM7", 9600);
port.Open();
while (true)
{
int input = Convert::ToInt32(Console::ReadLine());
    if (input == 1)
    port.Write("R");
    else if (input == 2)
    port.Write("G");
    else if (input == 3)
    port.Write("Y");
}
return 0;
   }
```

///// Arduino code ////
when the Arduino receive the data (1,2,3) it will make action by activating the servo motor

```
 void setup()

 {
 Serial.begin(9600);
 pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(motor, OUTPUT);
 Servo1.attach(servoPin1);
 Servo2.attach(servoPin2);
 Servo1.write(0); 
 Servo2.write(0); 
 }
 void loop(){

 digitalWrite(motor,HIGH);

 if(Serial.available()) 

  {
  int data = Serial.read();
  if(data == 'R')
  {
  digitalWrite(led,HIGH);

  Servo1.write(90); 
  Servo2.write(0); 
  }
  else if (data == 'G')
  {
  digitalWrite(led,LOW);

 Servo1.write(0); 
 Servo2.write(90); 
 }
  else if (data == 'Y')
  {
  digitalWrite(led,HIGH);

  Servo1.write(0); 
  Servo2.write(0); 
  }
```

//// OpenCV code ////
when the opencv detect the color of the object it will send number(1,2,3) indication for the color. 1= Red, 2 = Green, 3 = Yellow

```
    if (dArea_Red > 1.15609e+07 && dArea_Red < 1.40663e+07) {
        RED = 1;
        std::cout << "apple type "<< RED; // Red apple
    }
    if (dArea_Green > 1.46945e+07 && dArea_Green < 1.6315e+07) {
        GREEN = 2;
        std::cout << "apple type " << GREEN; // Red apple
    }

    if (dArea_Red > 2.5421e+06) {
        YELLOW = 3;
        std::cout << "apple type " << YELLOW; // Red apple
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue blocking you? Can you make an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: You may want to tag for `c++-cli` and remove one of the other tags.

Comment: Also I agree with @IvanRubinson it's not clear from the question what exactly is preventing you from achieving what you want. Is it a serial communications problem? If so you may want to focus on just that and remove the opencv component completely and the part with the motors. Both are irrelevant to solving a serial communications problem.

Comment: sorry for the unclear question.                                                                my issue is in the communication between the two program. I want to send the output from the opencv (1, 2, 3) to Arduino for action, I found some code and modified it and its work but when combine it with the opencv shows some error

Comment: from the founded code it uses conversion method to send the data, is there any simple way to send the output to the Arduino .                           I'm expecting three output (1,2,3)

Comment: You mean a compile error? If so edit your question and add the exact text of the compiler error. Copy that from the Output Tab (Alt+2) of Visual Studio.

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error LNK1104 cannot open file 'H:\Desktop\experiment4\x64\Debug\experiment4.exe' experiment4 H:\Desktop\experiment4\experiment4\LINK 1 
this massage shown when I add the communication code to the opencv, without it the program run fine

Comment: sorry for the lack of experience, I'm university student.

Comment: Does the file listed exist? If so perhaps it is still open from a previous execution.

Comment: Yeah sorry, this happen when I test it with and without the serial port. When compiling the code in line                               ( array<system::string^>^args) the string shows a red line with an error in the code. I know I should not use string because no need but I can’t figure out something else

Comment: I can't help with `system::string^` since that is not standard `c++`. You have tagged your question for standard `c++` instead of `c++-cli`